# Graph output on a remote server

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I am trying to create a series of graphs on a remote server using Base SAS.

SAS appears quite happy to produce graphs in a local session (Windows). This appears to be routed through the ODS HTML destination and appears in the Results window alongside the output of other procedures (Proc Print etc.). The HTML files are also saved in the local work folder in c:\Users\[id]\appdata\etc.

When I am connected to a remote server (Unix), non-graph procedures behave in the same way. These are appear in the Results window and are saved in the local work folder. However when I try to produce graph output I have issues.

Initially I get the error `ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access [pathname]` which is a location which I rightly do not have write access to.

I can use the code `ods listing gpath="%sysfunc(pathname(work))` to save the file to the remote work library, and could in theory use proc download to retrieve it, but this seems cumbersome.

So my question is: What settings can I use so that graph output behaves like it does in the local session?

Note that the Server appears to only have the listing destination active. I have also tried setting up a HTML destination on the remote server, but this just saves all output the the folder I specify on the remote server.

The data that I want to graph is too large to access directly. My other option is to use code which runs remotely to summarize it and then access that summary using a remote libname, but again this seems cumbersome.

I have also tried using both the ODS graphing utilities such as Proc SGPlot and the SAS/Graph utilities such as Proc GChart, but this doesn't seem to make a difference

TLDR: How do I set up ODS on a remote server so that graph output is automatically transferred to my local work folder and Results window in Base SAS

Comment: How are you connecting to Linux and running SAS there?  RSUBMIT from Windows SAS, Use Proc DOWNLOAD? SAS DMS or Batch on Linux? Enterprise Guide? Most general: Either mount a Windows share in Linux and write there, or create a Linux share that Windows can connect to and write there -- more cumbersome/politics setting up than using DOWNLOAD.  Alternative, output to a folder that a web server surfaces.

Comment: I was referring to using Base SAS on windows and using Rsubmit to run code on a lunix SAS server. Thanks for the suggestions I'll investigate how to set up a link for these. I also have access to EG, so the other option is just to use this. Perhaps I'm just a bit too used to my existing workflow